# PhpStorm форматирование кода, фигурная скобка

Tags: phpstorm

В чем собственно сам вопрос, поскольку я в основном работаю с C# то привык к "шарповскому" форматированию, и форматирование которое PhpStorm выполняет меня не совсем устраивает, конечно я полазил по настройкам и настроил форматирование по максимуму "как нужно" но один момент я или упустил или его там нету. Вообщем фрагмент кода

```
if($i == 0) {
    while (true) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Меня не устраивает автоформатирование фигурых скобок { в часности открывающихся, я хочу чтобы скобка открывалась на новой строке, короче вот так

```
if($i == 0) 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

для меня это более удобно и более привычно, и если есть способ так сделать в PhpStorm то будет хорошо, но повторюсь я такой возможности не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Settings</kbd> →

<kbd>Editor</kbd> → <kbd>Code Style</kbd> → <kbd>PHP</kbd> →

<kbd>Wrapping and Braces</kbd> → <kbd>Braces Placement</kbd> → <kbd>Other</kbd> → <kbd>Next line</kbd>

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это оно. Как я сам не заметил) Благодарю

Comment: Неудивительно. У *Jetbrains* сильно развесистый интерфейс и найти что-либо там сложновато.

Answer (score 2):

Всё настраивается тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`File` → `Settings` → `Editor` → `CodeStyle` → `PHP`

Конкретно скобки на вкладке `Wrapping and Braces`

Comment: Именно нужной мне функции там нету, и вообще там в основном функции для круглой скобки "(" а не для фигурной "{" круглую скобку можно настроить чтобы она вела себя так как мне нужно чтобы вела себя фигурная........

Comment: @pavver В смысле нет? Вы во всей вкладке `Wrapping and Braces` посмотрели?

Comment: @pavver kff написал тоже самое......однако здрасте... %)

Comment: kff указал именно на тут пункт, который я к сожалению не заметил сам Wrapping and Braces → Braces Placement → Other → Next line